# Triangle instead of circle in degrees

Tags: symbols, degrees

How does one turn the circular degree symbol  \textdegree

> °

into an equilateral triangle degree symbol?

I am just very curious about this, I only know how to type up basic mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple use `^` to make a triangle appear as a superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    $15^\triangle$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or even smaller but requiring another package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
    $15^\smalltriangleup$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sure. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I was interested in an alternative symbol for the hypothetical scenario where one full turn is defined to be something other than 360 units.

Comment: Note that `mathabx` redefines many math symbols. You may or may not want that.

Comment: @Alex you mean like radians or gradians?

Comment: @Alex Before doing something like that you should research the meaning of the "circle". It isn't at all related to the "full turn", which is more obvious when you realize it's used for temperature as well.

Comment: @pipe there are 360° in one full turn. The symbol is a circle, I don't know what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 3):

> I was interested in an alternative symbol for the hypothetical
> scenario where one full turn is defined to be something other than 360
> units.

Besides using other fonts, you may also draw your own symbols and use them like chracters. The code below:

- uses `tikz` and one of its libraries `shapes.geometric`, which provides a `star` shape
- the star can have other than 5 points and can degrade into a pentagon with its default of 5 beams
- to simplify use I introduced a shortcut `\turn`
- inside it simply draws and rescales the star `\tikz[scale=.5,transform shape]{\node[star,draw,star point height=7pt]{};}`
- to highlight some typographical effects the document simply repeats some text for the star and the triangle

[image: res]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% ~~~ cfor reating visuals ~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

% ~~~ shortcut ~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\turn[0]{\tikz[scale=.5,transform shape]{\node[star,draw,star point height=7pt]{};}}

% ~~~ document ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$. Some text using $15^{\turn}$.
    \bigskip
    
    Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. Some text using $15^\triangle$. 
\end{document}
```