# How to write monograms

Tags: letters, drop-cap

Is there a way to write monograms, such as these ones (maybe without the decorative frame)? I thought maybe there is a package for this purpose, but I couldn't find any one...
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, you will have to use a graphic. There is package that magically creates a monogram for you.

Comment: There exist so-called monogram fonts some of which might be free to use. (And I believe that what you show in the pictures are actually monograms created using such fonts.) These fonts partly use OpenType features to create ligatures from letters. If you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can just use these fonts in your document.

Comment: Usually you need a special font, but see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/530892

Comment: A starting point may be this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685905/245790 , which shows some basics of vectorizing bitmaps. // Once you can draw a monogram with tikz, here are some basics of using such drawings within text: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687896/triangle-instead-of-circle-in-degrees/687921#687921 . You certainly want to take a dive into baselines of letters and related topics.